# JTextArea editable or not editable depending on how it's called

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Total re-edit with compilable example that clarifies my issue.

Overall program: Class MainFrame displays a JTable with results from a SQL query. MainFrame also has JButtons for refreshing, adding, updating, and querying the table. Clicking the Update button makes visible a text area and submit button. Users can enter an id number into the text area. When they click submit a new frame, UpdateFrame, opens with all the data from the record the corresponds to the id number.

Stripped-down versions of MainFrame and UpdateFrame are below.

UpdateFrame2.java

```
package kft1task4;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class UpdateFrame2  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("This is a text area");
    UpdateFrame2() {
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(1000,400,1000,500);
        pane.setLayout(null);
        add(pane);
        jta.setBounds(110,100,100,15);
        pane.add(jta);
        }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        } //End actionListener
    } //End class
```

Very simple. One frame with one panel with one JTextArea. The JTextArea should be editable; I should be able to type in it.

MainFrame2.java

```
package kft1task4;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainFrame2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JButton closeButt = new JButton("Push me to close the program");
    JButton updateButt = new JButton("Push me to update a record");  
    JButton submitUpdButt = new JButton("Submit");   
    JLabel updateLabel = new JLabel("Select student id to update");
    JTextArea updateTA = new JTextArea();
MainFrame2(){
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(1000,200,1500,1000);
    pane.setLayout(null);
    add(pane);

    updateButt.setBounds(620,550,200,100);
    updateButt.addActionListener(this);
    pane.add(updateButt);        

    closeButt.setBounds(1290,550,200,100);
    closeButt.addActionListener(this);
    pane.add(closeButt);   

    submitUpdButt.setBounds(820,735,200,25);
    submitUpdButt.addActionListener(this);
    submitUpdButt.setVisible(false);
    pane.add(submitUpdButt);

    updateLabel.setBounds(620,700,200,15);
    updateLabel.setVisible(false);
    pane.add(updateLabel);

    updateTA.setBounds(820,700,200,15);
    updateTA.setVisible(false);
    pane.add(updateTA);
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();  
    if(source == closeButt){
        System.exit(0);
         }       
    if(source == updateButt){
        updateLabel.setVisible(true);
        updateTA.setVisible(true);
        submitUpdButt.setVisible(true);
         }       
    if(source == submitUpdButt){
         //submitUpdButt.setVisible(false);
         new UpdateFrame2();
         updateTA.setText(null);
         updateTA.setVisible(false);
         updateLabel.setVisible(false);
         submitUpdButt.setVisible(false);
         }
   }
}
```

Note the three fields: updateLabel, updateTA, and submitUpdButt (and please forgive the poor naming). When new MainFrame2() is first instantiated, those three fields are .setVisible(False). Clicking updateButt makes them visible.

Click submitUpdButt performs five actions: First, it instantiates a new UpdateFrame2(). Second, it clears the text from UpdateTA. Finally, it makes the three fields invisible. Those 5 actions complete with no problem.

Now here's the oddity: Notice that I've listed "submitUpdButt.setVisible(false)" twice. Once before "new UpdateFrame2()" and once after. I comment out one and leave other in place. If "submitUpdButt.setVisible(false)" appears *before* "new UpdateFrame2()," the UpdateFrame appears, and its text area is editable.

If "submitUpdButt.setVisible(false)" appears *after* "new UpdateFrame2()," as it's written above, the UpdateFrame appears. But its text area is *not* editable.

To clarify: Every other element of the program behaves exactly the same. The 3 fields appear and disappear as expected. The window open and close correctly. The text "This is a text area" appears where it should. No errors are produced. But the text area in UpdateFrame2 is editable or not based on where I put "submitUpdButt.setVisible(false)".

I hope this description is more clear than my last one.

Comment: st.studentID what type is? you should consider writing a SSCCE.org

Comment: You should include the code which actually involves the JTextAreas. That is, the code that initialises them and updates them.

Comment: @nachokk st.StudentID is an int.

Comment: @JustDanyul I rewrote a very simplified MainFrame class, and now the frames appear editable. I will paste the simplified class in a moment.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  You seem to have replied to @nachokk as though you were about to post one, but there is no SSCCE yet..

Comment: Ok. SSCCE (and much clearer description) posted.